# std::generate not working on an std::vector

Tags: c++, g++, stl-algorithm

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::mt19937 mt;
  std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(0, 255);
  int l = 500;
  std::vector<int> k(l);
  std::generate(k.begin(), k.end(), d(mt));
  return(0);
}
```

trying to compile with both `g++ 4.7.2` and `g++ 4.8.1` like so

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp
```

the reported error is

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:63:0,
                 from main.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::generate(_FIter, _FIter, _Generator) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Generator = int]’:
main.cpp:11:42:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:5083:2: error: ‘__gen’ cannot be used as a function
```

I don't have any clue or idea about what can be possibly wrong in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`std::generate` takes a function object and applies its return value to the sequence container. But `std::uniform_int_distribution<T>::operator ()` doesn't return a function object, it actually generates the random value and returns it. If you want to pass a functor, use a lambda:

```
std::generate(k.begin(), k.end(), [&] { return d(mt); });
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[Here is a working example of your program.](http://ideone.com/51hSXB#view_edit_box)

Comment: so `std::generate` requires a function object, it does **not** require a return value that it can assign to the container ?

Comment: @user2485710 It does. The return value will be whatever is returned by the lambda, and it will then be assigned to the container.

Comment: ops, I was convinced that I had already done that, thanks again.

Comment: @user2485710: Yes, `generate` needs a function object.  Think of what happens when you pass a value instead.  `generate` would have only one value to use for all 500 elements, it would have no way to generate new random values.